# What's the difference between "dismiss" and "refute"?

Tags: word-difference

> Trump quickly lashed out on Wednesday, **dismissing** the op-ed as "really
>   a disgrace" and "gutless" and assailing the author and The New York
>   Times for publishing the anonymous opinion piece.

[Trump slams damning New York Times op-ed as 'gutless'](https://edition.cnn.com/2018/09/05/politics/nyt-trump-resistance-op-ed/index.html)

Look dismiss up from dictionary, it means

> to refuse to consider someone’s idea, opinion etc, because you think
>   it is not serious, true, or important

I think it's similar to "refute".

Comment: Did you also look up *refute* in the dictionary?

Comment: @JasonBassford, Honestly, I just don't understand dismiss. In Chinese translation, it means, "don't care". If Trump really don't care this, Why did he "asailing" this? So, I think it may be means refute.

Comment: I have 2 sentences in an artical, "South African president rejects claims of Chinese "colonialism"", "South African President Cyril Ramaphosa on Monday dismissed allegations of China practicing colonialism in Africa". It seems dismiss have the same meaning with reject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to your question, here is the Merriam-Webster definition of [**refute**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/refute):

> **1** : to prove wrong by argument or evidence : show to be false or erroneous
>   **2** : to deny the truth or accuracy of • *refuted* the allegations

When you **refute** something, you say something *actively* against its claim. Even if it's just to say that it's "wrong," you are making an active statement in opposition to it.

---

To **dismiss** something it to not consider it at all. (As cited in your dictionary quote).

---

If using the second sense of **refute**, it's possible to both dismiss something *and* refute it:

> No, that's simply not true [**refute**], and I'm not going to discuss it any further [**dismiss**].

In the news story you quoted, Trump is dismissing the story but he's not saying it's false, let alone trying to *prove* that it's false. In other words, he's not refuting it in either sense of the word.

---

You said in a comment that in the Chinese translation, **dismiss** means "don't care." In English, it means "don't care *to discuss it further*."